# Let td's smoothly slide and fit to their new position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table border="0" class="ready-orders">
   <tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And dynamicly add td's with jQuery:

```
$('.ready-orders tr').append('<td style="display: none;"><h1>Random Name</h1><h2>Your order is ready!</h2></td>');
$('.ready-orders tr td:last-child').fadeIn('slow');
```

But then, the existing td's in the row jump very unbeautifully to their new position. I want to make this look better, without using .animation() (So that they kind of slide to their new position and change smoothly to their new width).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cDvd/) where you can see, how unnicely the old td's jump to the left.

Is there a nice and clean way to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you can apply a fixed height to the row, that should help.  It often jumps because the row resizes in response to the newly added content.  Setting a fixed height will prevent the height from adjusting while adding content.  You just have to know that you can always live within the height given.

Comment: My problem has nothing to do with the height. Lokk in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cDvd/). There you can see, how unnicely the old td's jump to left. How can I let them smoothly do this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting CSS3 transition duration to the tr like:

```
tr {
-webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease; 
-moz-transition: all 0.9s ease; 
-o-transition: all 0.9s ease; 
transition: all 0.9s ease; 
}
```

Any changes that affect the size of the tr will take the specified duration to adjust.

Let me know if it works.

Here is reference to understand CSS3 transitions (duration) more.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-duration.asp

Comment: Thank  you for your answer, but the width or the height of the row does not change at any point. But the amount, the position and the width of it's td's dynamicly changes and I only want to let them slowly go to their new position and fit to it, if they have to share their space in the row with a new td.

Comment: Then put that css style on whatever element that is changing, regardless if its height, width, or whatever.

Comment: It seems for me, that it does not apply to position change, or am I doinng something wrong?